# How to set an unspecified server in drain mode, log off user on a unspecified server, and finally take that server out of drain mode?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Drain mode, setting relative weight to 1, not allowing new reconnections any of these would work. I just need a PowerShell answer to this on a array of 10 Windows 2008 R2 servers.

I have gotten everything but the drain mode working so far.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
$username = Read-Host "Enter Username: "
$serverList = @("foo", "boo", "hullabaloo", "hoot")

foreach ($item in $serverList)
{
    if (quser $username /server:$item)
    {
        quser $username /server:$item
        Write-Host $username is at $item
        #Set $item to drain mode
        #logoff $username /server:item
        Sleep 60 -s
        #Set $item out of drain mode
    }
}
```

This is remotely from my desk.

I have answered the question myself below.

Comment: `chglogon /drain`?

Comment: I tried that but it does not work, is there a parameter for the specific server? Or something I need to do before typing the command?

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753586.aspx). `change logon` (or `chglogon` for short) doesn't have an option for running it remotely. You'd neet other means for that (like `psexec` or `Invoke-Command`). Why would you even want to set a server to drain mode for just 1 minute anyway?

Comment: Because @AnsgarWiechers our users have full rdp connections and sometimes logging them off and on doesn't work when they have a specific problem with an application, and they need to be sent to another rdp server. All of the computers automatically log themselves back on, so it only needs to be 1 minute. This happens enough that I wanted to streamline the process for my coworkers. We do not have the time or staff to fix all of the problems related to running outdated applications.

I did read the documentation, but it sounded like there was something I was missing, so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I would consider the automatic reconnect the part that requires fixing, but whatever. I'd suggest using `Invoke-Command` for running the RDP management commands on the remote hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the server to drain mode I did this:

```
    $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $item)

    $regKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\", $true)
    $regKey.SetValue("TSServerDrainMode", 2, 'DWORD')
    sleep -s 30
    Write-Host "30 more seconds."
    sleep -s 30
    $regKey.SetValue("TSServerDrainMode", 0, 'DWORD')
```